# Почему программа не закрывается методом psutil.terminate() и psutil.kill()

Tags: python, windows, ос, signal

Всем приввет подскажи пожалуйста какой способ лучще использовать. В начале я пробовал использовать библиотеку psutil. И ее возможности как terminate() и kill(). Но некоторые пороограммы например PUBG LITE, Discord не закрываются почему? Пробовал закрывать через библиотеку os. os.close(fd) и os.kill(pid, sig). Но как найти fd и sig значения я не понял. Хотя другие программы закрываются без проблем.

## подключаем нужные нам библиотеки

```
import psutil
import time
import os
import signal
# функция выводит в консоль весть список запущенных программ
for proc in psutil.process_iter(['pid', 'name']):
    print(proc.info)
# просим пользователя вести данные
x = int(input('Ведите pid программы:'))
times = int(input('Ведите время игры в минутах:'))
# тут находим родительский (основной) процесс.
# Потому-что если у программы монго под процессов то она может не закрыться.
p = psutil.Process(pid=x) # получаем информацию о процессе (pid, name, time)
r = int(p.ppid()) # получаем pid родительского (основного) процесса
times = times*60 # тут переводим минуты в секунды
print('ХОРОШО МОЖЕТЕ ИГРАТЬ ')
time.sleep(times) # задержка установленная пользователем
# делаем что-нибуть что бы пользоваеть понял что пора закругляться
print('пора закругляться')
time.sleep(300) # задержка перед проверкой закрыта ли программа если пользлватель нас игнорирует время в сек
# проверяем закрыта программа или нет
try: # если вееденные ниже действия вызывают ошибку то делается блок except:
    c = psutil.Process(pid=x) # тут будет ошибка если мы хотим узнать информацию о несуществующим процессе
    p = psutil.Process(pid=r) # переменная x r хрошят номер процесса информация о родительском процессе
except:
    print('пока')
    raise SystemExit # завершение моей программы
# если ошибки нет то делаем следуйщие действия
print('закрываю ее')
# завершение программы 2 способа
p.terminate()
p.kill()
#os.close()
#os.kill()
raise SystemExit
```

Comment: win api не пробовали ?

Comment: нет, но надо попробовать.